# How do I reset AppEngine password in IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I entered a wrong password when I deployed an AppEngine project using Tools -> Upload App Engine Application. How do I get IntelliJ to ask me for a new password? It just fails silently in the background now. My Admine Console in App Engine shows nothing is deployed.

Answer (score 3):

I managed that by removing this line

```
<property name="GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL" value="my_email_address@gmail.com" />
```

from my `workspace.xml`.

Comment: Where is it located? edit: ah: in .idea in your project folder

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured this out on Intellij Idea 13.

You should remove file **~/.IntelliJIdea13/config/options/security.xml**

**Pay attention**, this will remove all saved passwords because usernames are encrypted too, so you wouldn't know which entry matches your AppEngine authentication.

Then you should reconfigure IDE Settings -> Password option to reset master password.

Comment: I removed security.xml file and reset the master password as you said, but it did not solve the problem. Any other clues?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `.iml` file for your project, and edit it to remove the following lines:

```
<option name="email" value="user@host.com" />
<option name="gp" value="abcd1234" />
<option name="oauth2" value="false" />
```

You'll be prompted for your credentials again the next time you try to deploy to App Engine.

Answer (score -1):

You can force the AppEngine credentials dialog by selecting "Do not remember passwords" under Settings > Passwords.

Comment: It doesn't make IDEA forget the password.